# jquery next() and prev() not working

Tags: jquery

I facing some trouble with get value with jquery next and prev

how I can get next or prev value from sibling
when I click next or prev it will store value and it will be updated everytime where class show move.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
});
var currentIndex = 0;
var boxTotal = $('.content').length;
var boxIndex = $('.content.show').index();

var imgNext = $('.content.show').next().text();
var imgPrev = $('.content.show').prev().text();

function cycleItems() {
  var box = $('.content').eq(currentIndex);
  box.siblings().removeClass('show');
  box.addClass('show');
}

function boxNext(){
  currentIndex ++;
  if (currentIndex > boxTotal - 1) {
    currentIndex = 0;
  }
}

function boxPrev(){
  currentIndex --;
  if (currentIndex < 0) {
    currentIndex = boxTotal - 1;
  }
}

$('.next').click(function() {
  boxNext();
  cycleItems();
  $('.valPrev').text('is '+imgPrev);
  $('.valNext').text('is '+imgNext);
});

$('.prev').click(function() {
  boxPrev();
  cycleItems();
  $('.valPrev').text('is '+imgPrev);
  $('.valNext').text('is '+imgNext);
});
```

```css
.content{
  display: none;
}

.content.show{
  display: block;
}
.content img{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.prev img, .next img{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div class="content"><span>1</span></div>
  
  <div class="content show"><span>2</span></div>
  
  <div class="content"><span>3</span></div>
  
  <div class="content"><span>4</span></div>
  
  <div class="content"><span>5</span></div>
</div>


<div class="prev">
<label>Prev</label> <span class="valPrev"></span>
</div>
<div class="next"> 
<label>Next</label> <span class="valNext"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: It is because you set the value at the start and never sets the value again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you only set `imgNext` and `imgPrev` on load. You instead need to update them when one of the labels is clicked. The simplest and most DRY way to do that would be to put the code that updates the values in the `cycleItems` function, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var currentIndex = 0;
  var boxTotal = $('.content').length;
  var boxIndex = $('.content.show').index();

  function cycleItems() {
    $('.content').eq(currentIndex).addClass('show').siblings().removeClass('show');
    var imgNext = $('.content.show').next().text();
    var imgPrev = $('.content.show').prev().text();
    $('.valPrev').text('is ' + imgPrev);
    $('.valNext').text('is ' + imgNext);
  }

  $('.next').click(function() {
    currentIndex++;
    if (currentIndex > boxTotal - 1)
      currentIndex = 0;

    cycleItems();
  });

  $('.prev').click(function() {
    currentIndex--;
    if (currentIndex < 0)
      currentIndex = boxTotal - 1;

    cycleItems();
  });
});
```

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}

.content.show {
  display: block;
}

.content img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.prev img,
.next img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div class="content"><span>1</span></div>
  <div class="content show"><span>2</span></div>
  <div class="content"><span>3</span></div>
  <div class="content"><span>4</span></div>
  <div class="content"><span>5</span></div>
</div>

<div class="prev">
  <label>Prev</label> <span class="valPrev"></span>
</div>
<div class="next">
  <label>Next</label> <span class="valNext"></span>
</div>
```

Note that I simplified the logic in places too.

Comment: I see, so it will run along with cycleItems everytime I click. thanks for advice

Answer (score 0):

You mean this? You need to get the text each time before changing stuff

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  var currentIndex = 0;
  var boxTotal = $('.content').length;
  var boxIndex = $('.content.show').index();


  function cycleItems() {
    var imgNext = $('.content.show').next().text();
    var imgPrev = $('.content.show').prev().text();
    $('.valPrev').text('is ' + imgPrev);
    $('.valNext').text('is ' + imgNext);

    var box = $('.content').eq(currentIndex);
    box.siblings().removeClass('show');
    box.addClass('show');

  }

  function boxNext() {
    currentIndex++;
    if (currentIndex > boxTotal - 1) {
      currentIndex = 0;
    }
  }

  function boxPrev() {
    currentIndex--;
    if (currentIndex < 0) {
      currentIndex = boxTotal - 1;
    }
  }

  $('.next').click(function() {
    boxNext();
    cycleItems();
  });

  $('.prev').click(function() {
    boxPrev();
    cycleItems();
  });
});
```

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}

.content.show {
  display: block;
}

.content img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.prev img,
.next img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div class="content"><span>1</span></div>

  <div class="content show"><span>2</span></div>

  <div class="content"><span>3</span></div>

  <div class="content"><span>4</span></div>

  <div class="content"><span>5</span></div>
</div>


<div class="prev">
  <label>Prev</label> <span class="valPrev"></span>
</div>
<div class="next">
  <label>Next</label> <span class="valNext"></span>
</div>
```